# I am unable to break a loop that repeatedly asks for user input. Anyone know how to solve this?

Tags: ruby, io

I am trying to create a loop that will ask the user for an integer and will then print "hi" an integer number of times and then ask for input again. I then want the loop to break if the user inputs "bye".

my code so far:

```
 def hi_hi_goodbye
   loop do
     number = gets

      (number.to_i).times do 
          print "hi" 
      end

      break if 
          gets == "bye"
      end

 end
```

My code so far will not loop. It receives the integer and prints "hi" a given amount of times. However, I am unable to break the loop.

Comment: so where do you actually CHANGE `gets`?

Comment: By the looks of your code, you got a SyntaxError that said something about `end` and so you added `end`s everywhere until the error went away. But what, exactly, is the `end` in `print "hi" end` doing? What is the second-to-last `end` doing? If you take the time to reformat your code with conventional indentation, you'll see why your code is now not doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that Jordan. That was a typo on my part. I have edited it out now. I typed the question too quickly and due to frustration, I forgot to re-read. Apologies.

My question still stands though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 break if gets.chomp == "bye"
```

This is so because your input would be something like `bye\n`, so your condition always false, because `gets` takes even the enter.

Comment: I explained why. Because `bye\n` will never be equal to `bye`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.

 I never realized it takes even the enter!